# using d3.js in three.js project - HOWTO?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, three.js, tween

Greetings experts and fellow programmers...

I experimented a bit with d3.js and I found a nice example for an animated analog clock here:

```
http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=d3%20analog%20clock&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ericbullington.com%2Farticles%2F2012%2F10%2F27%2Fd3-oclock&ei=NNgIUuCqKomsOKmDgMAK&usg=AFQjCNGoI2g7XQIguM_6UM5V_6WzeJyPxA&bvm=bv.50500085,d.bGE
```

I changed it into 4 clocks, showing local time, London, New York and Hong Kong time simultaneously...

The code (snippet) looks like this:

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HEAD>
<META content="IE=10.000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<META charset="utf-8">     
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<SCRIPT src="d3.v2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="clock.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>      
<BODY>
<DIV class="herechart"></DIV>
<DIV class="londonchart"></DIV>
<DIV class="newyorkchart"></DIV>
<DIV class="hongkongchart"></DIV>
<SCRIPT src="clock.js"></SCRIPT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

clock.js (revised):

```
(function() {
  var clockGroup, fields, formatHour, formatMinute, formatSecond, height, offSetX, offSetY, pi, render, scaleHours, scaleSecsMins, vis, width;
  formatSecond = d3.time.format("%S");
  formatMinute = d3.time.format("%M");
  formatHour = d3.time.format("%H");
  herefields = function() {
    var d, data, hour, minute, second;
    d = new Date();
    second = d.getSeconds();
    minute = d.getMinutes();
    hour = d.getHours() + minute / 60;
    return data = [
      { "unit": "seconds", "text": formatSecond(d), "numeric": second },
      { "unit": "minutes", "text": formatMinute(d), "numeric": minute },
      { "unit": "hours", "text": formatHour(d), "numeric": hour }
    ];
  };
  londonfields = function() {
  // fields creating in the same way as in herfields function
  };
  newyorkfields = function() {
  // you get the idea
  };
  hongkongfields ) = function {
  // i did it again
  };
  width = 82;
  height = 82;
  offSetX = 82;
  offSetY = 82;
  pi = Math.PI;
  scaleSecsMins = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 59 + 59 / 60]).range([0, 2 * pi]);
  scaleHours = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 11 + 59 / 60]).range([0, 2 * pi]);

  // creating local clock frame
  vis = d3.selectAll(".herechart").append("svg:svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
  clockGroup = vis.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + offSetX + "," + offSetY + ")");

  // creating London time clock frame
  londonvis = d3.selectAll(".londonchart").append("svg:svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
  londonGroup = londonvis.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 260 + "," + -4 + ")");

  // omitting creation of the two other clock frames

  // ommitting creation of clock hands (using .append(...)) and texts alltogether - see web example

  // render function
  render = function(heredata, londondata, newyorkdata, hongkongdata) {
    var hourArc, minuteArc, secondArc;
    clockGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").remove();
    londonGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").remove();
    newyorkGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").remove();
    hongkongGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").remove();

    secondArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(70).startAngle(function(d) { return scaleSecsMins(d.numeric); }).endAngle(function(d) { return scaleSecsMins(d.numeric); });
    minuteArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(66).startAngle(function(d) { return scaleSecsMins(d.numeric); }).endAngle(function(d) { return scaleSecsMins(d.numeric); });
    hourArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(50).startAngle(function(d) { return scaleHours(d.numeric % 12); }).endAngle(function(d) { return scaleHours(d.numeric % 12); });

    clockGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").data(heredata).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return secondArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return minuteArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return hourArc(d); }
    }).attr("class", "clockhand").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return 1; } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return 3; } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return 3; } }).attr("fill", "none");

    londonGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").data(londondata).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return secondArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return minuteArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return hourArc(d); }
    }).attr("class", "clockhand").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return 1; } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return 3; } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return 3; } }).attr("fill", "none");

    newyorkGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").data(newyorkdata).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return secondArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return minuteArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return hourArc(d); }
    }).attr("class", "clockhand").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return 1; } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return 3; } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return 3; } }).attr("fill", "none");

    hongkongGroup.selectAll(".clockhand").data(hongkongdata).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return secondArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return minuteArc(d); } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return hourArc(d); }
    }).attr("class", "clockhand").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", function(d) { if (d.unit === "seconds") { return 1; } else if (d.unit === "minutes") { return 3; } else if (d.unit === "hours") { return 3; } }).attr("fill", "none");
  };
  // end of render function

  // periodically getting time fields and give them to render function
  setInterval(function() {
    var data;
    heredata = herefields();
    londondata = londonfields();
    newyorkdata = newyorkfields();
    hongkongdata = hongkongfields();
    return render(heredata, londondata, newyorkdata, hongkongdata);
  }, 1000); }).call(this);
```

That code work well for me.

But I would LOVE to include that into a three.js project of mine, where I am using two scenes with two different renderers (one canvas, one css3d renderer) in one projection. I am doing a lot of flying and rotatin' around there... :-)

As the D3 objects are DIVs, I thought I can create CSS3D-rendered objects and fly them (TWEENING and changing positions) around with the other objects.

Is there a way to do it? And how can this be done.

Below, I show some of the code that I am using in my three.js project where there is an init() function which CREATES DIVs and scene,renderers and projections... I cut out heavily on designing particles and DIVs plus alot of stuff for changing these elements while animating them.... the code below works very well (not the snippet, but the full code). But how do I combine them?

```
<body onload="connameinit();">
    <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/tween.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var program = function ( context ) {

                myindex++;
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect( 3, 12, 7, 1);
                context.drawImage(backgroundImage01, 0, 0);

                context.closePath();
                context.fill();
            }
            group = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add( group );
            for ( var i = 0; i < 400; i++ ) {
                particle = new THREE.Particle( new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial( { map: new THREE.Texture( generateSprite() ), color: Math.random() * 0x808008 + 0x808080, program: program } ) );
                particle.position.x = Math.random() * 6000 - 3000;
                particle.position.y = Math.random() * 6000 - 3000;
                particle.position.z = Math.random() * 6000 - 5500;
                particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = Math.random() * 3 + 2;
                initParticle( particle, i * 10 );
                group.add( particle );
                myparticles.push( particle );
            }
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            // creating the CSS3D rendered object
            scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
            var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
            element.className = 'element';
            element.style.width = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight * 1400) + 'px';
            element.style.height = '1400px';
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
            var profile = document.createElement( 'div' );
            profile.className = 'profile';
            profile.textContent = "";
            element.appendChild( profile );
            myimgdiv = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
            myimgdiv.position.x = 0;
            myimgdiv.position.y = 0;
            myimgdiv.position.z = 0;
            scene2.add( myimgdiv );
            renderer2 = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
            renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            renderer2.domElement.style.top = 0;
            document.body.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            TWEEN.update();
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            mypindex = mypindex + mypmul;
            if (mypindex > 500) {
                mymulti = - mymulti;
                mypmul = -1;
            }
            if (mypindex < -500) {
                mymulti = - mymulti;
                mypmul = 1;
            }
            group.rotation.x += mymulti * 0.0003;
            group.rotation.y += mymulti * 0.0006;
            myimgdiv.scale.x += mymulti * 0.0001;
            myimgdiv.scale.y += mymulti * 0.0001;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            renderer2.render( scene2, camera );
        }
        function mydivtransform( targets, duration ) {
                var object = myimgdiv;
                var target = targets[ 0 ];
                new TWEEN.Tween( object.position )
                    .to( { x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y, z: object.position.z }, duration )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
                    .start();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I create the clock DIVs in the init() loop instead of placing the  code inside the body of the document. I would then somehow split the clock.js code and put part of it within the init() loop, but could somebody help me with that? I though, best way would be a third scene, using a third renderer (CSS3D), using the same projector.
But how can I create Three.js mashes from the D3 objects?
And how can I make sure that the animation of the clock hands continues while these Three.js objects are moved or TWEENed?

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Oliver

Comment: You might want to check out http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/

Comment: @OliR - Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still do not have a clue. If there would be a working example with a D3 clock being moved or tweened with three.js, I could go Forward from that.